# en una app android que envío a Play Console me reporta error con recursos de sonido alojados en /res/raw

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Inclusive estos archivos de sonido alojados en /res/raw aparecen con un icono con un signo de interrogación azul en la parte inferior derecha. Al correr mi aplicación localmente (en mi cel) o instalar la apk en otros dispositivos funciona perfectamente, pero al enviarla a Play Console para su publicación me reporta l siguiente:

```
Problema: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/xxxx.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0000
```

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 17039
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.xxxxxx/com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/acelerometro.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0000
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/acelerometro.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0000
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:291)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1267)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:931)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:914)
    at com.jgalicia.alertacaidas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:205)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:460)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:289)
    ... 16 more
```

La imagen de mis recursos en res/raw es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
/**
     * Sonidos
     */
    private MediaPlayer soundAcc;
    private MediaPlayer soundGyro;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Instanciate the sound to use

        soundAcc = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.acelerometro);
        soundGyro = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.emergency028);

}      

    protected void onResume() {

       vibrador.vibrate(750);
                        soundAcc.start();

......}
```

Alguien ha tenido este problema? Gracias y saludos!

Comment: veo que quitaste el punto, ¿no te sirvió la respuesta?

Comment: Disculpa, fue involuntario, saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica que no encuentra un recurso, pero el problema en realidad es que este no puede abrirse posiblemente por la compresion con la cual se creo

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/raw/acelerometro.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0000 at
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened
>   as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
>       at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)

Personalmente no he necesitado algun cambio leyendo archivos .mp3 desde el directorio raw, pero te sugiero deshabilitar la compresion para los archivos de este tipo.

Dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`

```
android {

    ...
    ...
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "mp3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah bien, intentaré eso. Es raro, porque le he dado muchas vueltas e inclusive me aceptó varias versiones en la PLay Console, en alguno de esos uploads algo pasó y empezaron a reportarme el error, aunque el codigo no ha cambiado. Gracias, te comento que pasa con el cambio. Saludos.

Comment: tu respuesta fue excelente. agregué las opciones en el build.gradle y todo funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias y saludos!